# R - Get formals from call object

Tags: r

How can I get the formals (arguments) from a call object?   formals() only seems to work with functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, a call does not *have* formals, only actual arguments... The difference being that a function like `foo <- function(x, y, ..., z=42)` can be *called* with *actual* arguments like `foo(42, bar=13)`.

...But getting the arguments can be done like this:

```
a <- call('foo', a=42, 13)
as.list(a)[-1]
#$a
#[1] 42
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 13
```

...on the other hand, you can usually (not always) find the actual function and find the formals for it:

```
a <- quote(which(letters=='g'))
formals(match.fun(a[[1]]))
#$x
#
#$arr.ind
#[1] FALSE
#
#$useNames
#[1] TRUE
```

Here you'd need to add some error handling if the function can't be found (as with the call to `foo` above)...

Comment: You don't have to coerce the call to a list - you can just work with it as a list, as long as you remember the first element is the function.  Also you probably want `match.call` rather than `match.fun` - that way you can combine the default and supplied arguments.

Comment: Well you wouldn't want `match.call` instead of `match.fun` but it's a useful addition: `match.call(eval(a[[1]]), a)`

Comment: @hadley - Thanks for mentioning `match.call`. Not coercing to a list can work if you know exactly what your doing - but `a[-1]` will print very weirdly, and can't be passed as args to `do.call` for example...